# Xcode 6 swift multiple segues with prepare for segue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm currently working on an app with one main `ViewController` and 2 other `ViewControllers`.
One is my browser which is working fine and the other one is a `TableView`.
I have 5 `Buttons` which lead me to my browser and one which should go to my `TableView`.
I've connected the `Button` with a **Present Modally** `segue` to my `TableView` controller (which has embeded in a `NavigationViewController`).
But every time I try to push the button the simulator crashes and this error appears:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x10b9bf860:  pushq  %rbp
0x10b9bf861:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10b9bf864:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x10b9bf867:  je     0x10b9bf89e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10b9bf869:  movabsq $-0x7fffffffffffffff, %rax
0x10b9bf873:  testq  %rax, %rdi
0x10b9bf876:  jne    0x10b9bf89e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10b9bf878:  leaq   0xb52e9(%rip), %rax
0x10b9bf87f:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x10b9bf882:  andq   (%rdi), %rax
0x10b9bf885:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x10b9bf890:  cmpq   %rsi, %rax
0x10b9bf893:  je     0x10b9bf8ad               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
0x10b9bf895:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
0x10b9bf899:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x10b9bf89c:  jne    0x10b9bf890               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x10b9bf89e:  leaq   0x36b7d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10b9bf8a5:  movq   %rax, 0xb4c0c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10b9bf8ac:  int3   
0x10b9bf8ad:  movq   %rdi, %rax
0x10b9bf8b0:  popq   %rbp
0x10b9bf8b1:  retq   
0x10b9bf8b2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

It won't work as well if I connect my segue to another viewcontroller or if I'm using other buttons.

I know the problem is somewhere in this code because if I delete it everything works just fine:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {


    var DestViewConroller : WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as WebViewController



    if (segue.identifier == "homeSegue"){

        DestViewConroller.url = "https://edu.sh.ch"


    }

    if (segue.identifier == "mailSegue"){

        DestViewConroller.url = "https://edumail.sh.ch/owa"

    }

    if (segue.identifier == "mensaSegue"){

        DestViewConroller.url = "http://kanti.sh.ch/fileadmin/Redaktoren/Service/Mensa/Menueplan.pdf"

    }

    if (segue.identifier == "absenzenSegue"){

        DestViewConroller.url = "https://edu.sh.ch/Lists/Absenzen/Heute%20%20Knftige.aspx"

    }

    if (segue.identifier == "stundenplanSegue"){

        DestViewConroller.url = "https://edu.sh.ch/Informationen/Stundenplaene/SiteAssets/SitePages/Homepage/klassen_03_juli.pdf"


    }



}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you also specify which identifier leads to which view controller?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a navigation controller?

Comment: every segue leads to my browser which works, only the button with no identifier/ no code which shoul lead me to a navigation controller is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error log mentions that

> Swift dynamic cast failed

So this means that the problem occurs when swift tries to cast `segue.destinationViewController` to `WebViewController`.

This will only happen when the `destinationViewController` is not a `WebViewController`.

Which is what happens when the app tries to segue to the `tableViewController` you mentioned.

Therefore to fix this error you have to initialise `DestViewController` inside each if condition or check if segue's identifier is not the identifier for tableViewController and then initialise and cast the `destinationViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the navigation controller is the destination, so you have to do something like this:

```
var webViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as?
 UINavigationController)?.viewControllers[0] as? webViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

This **segue/dynamic cast failed** issue seems to pop up a lot, but it's easy to fix.

If your webview controller was embedded in a `UINavigationController`, then `segue.destinationViewController` is a `UINavigationController` instance, not a `DestViewController` instance.

You probably could have kept your navigation controller and replaced this line:

`var DestViewConroller : WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as WebViewController`

with this:

`var DestViewConroller : WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as WebViewController`

the `.topViewController` property of `UINavigationController` refers to the top of the navigation stack, which should be your `DestViewConroller`

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in the object cast.
Make sure you have set the class of `DestViewConroller`  to `WebViewController` in the Storyboard. If you don't, DestViewConroller will be assumed to be an instance of UIViewController despite the cast.